# Removing object from CCArray not working

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'd like to remove a NSNumber from a CCArray. When I use `removeObject:` to remove a NSNumber of 13 or above nothing gets removed. What's going on here? I've tried using an NSMutableArray and it works fine. Using `removeObjectAtIndex:` is not an option because my array wont be in numerical order.

```
CCArray *arr = [CCArray array];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}

// Outputs arr count 20 
CCLOG(@"%@: arr count %i ", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [arr count]);

[arr removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:13]];

// Still outputs arr count 20  
CCLOG(@"%@: arr count %i ", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [arr count]);
```

Comment: What does [arr getIndexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:13]] return? A valid index, or NSNotFound? It might be worth printing out what each element in arr is, just as a sanity check. I can't see why it wouldn't be there...

Comment: CCLOG(@" %i ", [arr indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:13]]); placed at the end of the above code returns 2147483647.

Comment: I'm guessing that's NSNotFound. I think it is something to do with equality testing of objects. Create two separate variables of type NSNumber, both set to 13, then test one against the other - does it see them as equal? (Sorry, I don't know coco).

Comment: Resolved here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/30088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can verify that this seems to be a problem. Although I was able to call removeObject successfully, indexOfObject: returned NSNotFound. I rewrote the test case, and the error was gone. One more reason to stay away from CCArray I suppose.

I suggest to use NSMutableArray in this case. The [slightly better performance of CCArray](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/depth-ios-cocos2d-performance-analysis-test-project/#array) will not be reflected in better framerate, especially not for an array that has 20 elements. Besides, correct code is always better than code that's faster but incorrect.

Comment: It's kind of ironic that your screen name is 'Learn Cocos 2D', and yet you are saying to not use a fundamental part of cocos2d.

Comment: So I took the time to help you diagnose that problem... and he gets the credit? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Richard: hence my screen name isn't 'Love Cocos2D' :)  There's plenty of things about Cocos2D that I would have done differently. Not replacing NSMutableArray with CCArray is what I would have done, especially after performance tests showed that you can get only around 5% better framerate in synthetic tests. CCArray has proven to be problematic in a number of ways. I'm not using it anymore in my own code, because if I ever need more performance, there's always plenty of other (and better) opportunities for optimization.